# Removing aspect-ratio and using padding-top: 56.25%; instead

Tags: html, css, background, padding, aspect-ratio

How that is written into the code, I don't know.

How do I do that here? https://jsfiddle.net/37qob51s/

I tried asking AI, but it wasn't able to help.

Anyone know how this would be done?

I was told it can be done.

All I am doing is replacing `aspect-ratio: 1;` with, `padding-top: 56.25%;` in the code.

```css
:root {
  --color-a: #1155cc;
  --color-b: black;
  --color-c: #1155cc;
  --color-d: black;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #121212;
  padding: 50px 8px;
}

.panel-left,
.panel-right {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  top: 0%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform 3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  transition-delay: 1s;
}

.panel-left {
  left: 0;
}

.panel-right {
  right: 0;
}

.panel-left::before,
.panel-right::before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: black;
}

.panel-right::before {
  left: -100%;
}

body:hover .panel-left {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

body:hover .panel-right {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
.inner {
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.panel-right .inner {
  left: -100%;
}

.inner span,
.inner span:before,
.inner span:after,
.inner:before,
.inner:after {
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.inner:before {
  content: "";
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/z5MMJnv.png);
}

.inner:after {
  content: "";
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/8Jf8LLc.png);
}

.inner span {
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/5u16syR.png);
  position: relative;
}

.inner span:before,
.inner span:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0 0 0 0;
}

.inner span:before {
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/ygTtvme.png);
  transform: translateX(-99.99%);
}

.inner span:after {
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/QziKNDW.png);
  transform: translateX(99.99%);
}

.inner span,
.inner span:before,
.inner span:after,
.inner:before,
.inner:after {
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-left">
  <div class="inner"><span></span></div>
</div>

<div class="panel-right">
  <div class="inner"><span></span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add a picture to show the expected result ? Do you want the background to be placed on top of the video and cover it or do you want only the borders of the video to be black?

Comment: You did not include the pseudo elements in your fiddles css, the *before* and *after* styling.

Comment: can you tell me why you don't want `aspect-ratio` for this? I think it's already the good way to achieve what you desire. It's possible to use something like `padding-top`, but it will be more hacky

Comment: That is alright, it is code I just want to have saved as part of my other saved codes.

Comment: Is it able to be done in the code?

Comment: We can't simply replace `aspect-ratio` with `padding-top`, might need to add some more HTML, or even add svg or img elements, is it fine?

Comment: sure, that is fine.

Answer (score 2):

First off, the equivalent of `aspect-ratio:1` isn't `padding-top:56.25%`, it's `padding-top:100%`.

`56.25%` is equivalent to `aspect-ratio: 16/9;`, which is a rectangle.

Secondly, there's two reasons why this code isn't working.

- spans can't use padding, unless they have `display:inline-block` or `display:block`
- `padding-top works to define an aspect-ratio if you're using a pre-defined width and an 'auto' height`, which is the exact opposite of what you're doing here. Your spans have a predefined height(!!), not a predefined width, and so therefore you're going to need to re-build the whole thing from scratch using pre-defined width instead, if you want to be using `padding-top` instead of `aspect-ratio`.

That is to say, You can't use `height:100%` together with `padding-top` to preserve aspect ratio. Only when using `height:0px; width:100%;` would it work, but doing that would require rebuilding this whole design from zero.

Codepen which demonstrates the problem: https://codepen.io/Terrafire123/pen/ZEPgzwe

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace `aspect-ratio: 1` with `aspect-ratio: 16/9`.

Using `padding-top` to create elements with a fixed aspect ratio is a hack that was used before CSS offered proper support for it. To get a responsive 16:9 element we used to specify `padding-top: 56.25%` and `height: 0`. Going forward, please use `aspect-ratio` instead.

```css
:root {
  --color-a: #1155cc;
  --color-b: black;
  --color-c: #1155cc;
  --color-d: black;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #121212;
  padding: 50px 8px;
}

.panel-left,
.panel-right {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  top: 0%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform 3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  transition-delay: 1s;
}

.panel-left {
  left: 0;
}

.panel-right {
  right: 0;
}

.panel-left::before,
.panel-right::before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: black;
}

.panel-right::before {
  left: -100%;
}

body:hover .panel-left {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

body:hover .panel-right {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
.inner {
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.panel-right .inner {
  left: -100%;
}

.inner span,
.inner span:before,
.inner span:after,
.inner:before,
.inner:after {
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.inner:before {
  content: "";
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/z5MMJnv.png);
}

.inner:after {
  content: "";
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/8Jf8LLc.png);
}

.inner span {
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/5u16syR.png);
  position: relative;
}

.inner span:before,
.inner span:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0 0 0 0;
}

.inner span:before {
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/ygTtvme.png);
  transform: translateX(-99.99%);
}

.inner span:after {
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/QziKNDW.png);
  transform: translateX(99.99%);
}

.inner span,
.inner span:before,
.inner span:after,
.inner:before,
.inner:after {
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-left">
  <div class="inner"><span></span></div>
</div>

<div class="panel-right">
  <div class="inner"><span></span></div>
</div>
```